# PyTorch - modifications of autograd variables

Tags: python, gradient, torch, pytorch, autograd

In my PyTorch program, I have a matrix which is continuously updated over runtime.

I wonder how to perform this update. I tried using something like this:

```
matrix[0, index] = hidden[0]
```

Both `matrix` and `hidden` are autograd Variables. When using the example above I'm getting the following error message:

```
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation
```

I wonder how to get around this and perform the update without using in-place operations.

Probably slicing the matrix and creating a new matrix with torch.cat would work, but this doesn't seem to be a very nice solution.

Is there a better way doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe posting a piece of code could help, but have you tried using a dataset ? You could sequentially run through data efficiently with it.

http://pytorch.org/docs/master/data.html#torch.utils.data.TensorDataset

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I solved the problem using index_copy() which works fine and efficiently and lets me modify the matrix without in-place OP.
But your link still looks very interesting, previously I was looking for something similar. Very good to know, thx a lot!
(I cannot import torch.utils.data but I guess it was added later than v0.3.1.)

Comment: You're welcome :)  Right, it seems that it was added in v0.4